# Mailtrap: Sending email to the server failed

Tags: scala, email, playframework-2.3

I need to send emails with my playframework app but for the tests I want to use Mailtrap instead of a real smtp server.

I use the mailing configuration on the website that is under java/scala -> play section:

```
mail.smtp.host=mailtrap.io
mail.smtp.port=2525
mail.smtp.user=************
mail.smtp.pass=************
mail.smtp.channel="starttls"   <-I added this line myself
mail.from = "noreply@myapp.com"<-I added this line myself
```

When the app is running I try to send a email every one minute to test the mailer.

But at the first sending, it returns me the error:

```
[ERROR] [05/19/2015 09:34:56.397] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://application/user/$d] Sending the email to the following server failed : mailtrap.io:2525
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mailtrap.io:2525
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at email.Mailer$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Mailer.scala:35)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at email.Mailer.aroundReceive(Mailer.scala:10)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mailtrap.io, port: 2525;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:317)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
    ... 20 more

[ERROR] [05/19/2015 09:34:57.401] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://application/user/$d] Sending the email to the following server failed : mailtrap.io:2525
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mailtrap.io:2525
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at email.Mailer$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Mailer.scala:35)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at email.Mailer.aroundReceive(Mailer.scala:10)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mailtrap.io, port: 2525;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:317)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
    ... 20 more
```

I'm sorry of putting a so big error in front of your eyes but if anybody know what I made wrong, it may help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Can you telnet on port 25 from where you app is running to mailtrap.io? That backtrace is telling you there is no route. So it's nothing to do with your app, the mailtrap.io server just can't be reached

Comment: This doesn't works, the server can't be reached somehow...
Sorry for the time of response, haven't seen that you responded

Comment: Then it's nothing at all to do with your application, you need to fix the connectivity problem first.